# XSS leak when not using htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, xss

Some one told me that this code is open to XSS LEAK... I tried googling it and not much information showed up, except just ways how to perform the leak.

My question is what am I really subseptible if I am not using `htmlspecialchars()`, can someone edit a `$_POST[]` variable to be `<?=$db_password?>`... I thought that PHP was processed on the server, so I didn't think that would work, right? What can they really do that is harmful with the code below??

I am using prepared statements to insert these values into MySQL.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_POST['id']?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?=$_POST['name']?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ordernum" value="<?=$_POST['ordernum']?>"/>

    <?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['ordernum']; $i++){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="line'.$i.'" value="'.$_POST['line'.$i].'" />';
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually know what [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is.

Comment: Okay, so I read the link... and it seems like you can duplicate/impersonate websites to send you someone else session information. Or even hijack someone's session to impersonate them while logged on. But I am not using sessions, does that mean that it doesn't apply to this code?

Comment: XSS can also be used to cause someone to do something he didn't intend to do, that by injecting Javascript and having it preform actions

Comment: @nrathaus but this person would need to click on an infected link right? This won't apply to all the users who go directly to the site?

Comment: Yes they would need to be tricked into clicking on malcious links, or just visit a hostile site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's an open floodgate for security issues: you're outputting $_POST data as is.

At the very least `htmlspecialchars()`, and more likely `strip_tags()`, anything you put in field attributes. But even then you're still not safe. Some colorful samples of dirty input that can potentially land in there:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

To work around those, you want to use filtering libraries such as this:

http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Comment: Is htmlpurifier safe to use over time? I seem's like it is maintained by one individual.

Comment: HTML purifier has been maintained for as long as I can remember running into it (2006 or so), and there's a [Symfony bundle](https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle) for it, so methinks it's a safe bet. Personally, I only ever use WordPress when doing PHP, and its various `esc_*()` functions (which are a fork of kses) are well maintained.